# Supply path data to OpenStreetMaps or Bing Maps

Tags: openstreetmap, bing-maps

Bing is comprehensive and it isn't Google. Also I was given to understand that Bing maps integrates OpenStreetMaps data. An answer for OpenStreetMaps would also be acceptable; it's the capability that matters: construct a URL that causes a browser to show a path on a map.

I don't want to embed Bing maps as a control in a web application. I want to construct an HTTP request (GET or POST) to launch Bing maps in its own right in another tab or browser supplying a small series of points (probably GPX format) to be shown as a route on the map.

It's the structure of the URL (and payload if applicable) that interest me. If you want to put code in an answer Javascript, Typescript or server side C# are all no problem.

When I research this I find loads of info on using an API to request a route between two points. This would be fabulous if I were trying to create yet another nav app but the requirement here is simply *show this series of points as a path on a map*.

I can do it for a single point (sample lifted from another question's answer) [https://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=53.0210235~-1.48398532&lvl=16&dir=0&sty=c&sp=point.53.0210235_-1.48398532_My%20Phone](https://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=53.0210235%7E-1.48398532&lvl=16&dir=0&sty=c&sp=point.53.0210235_-1.48398532_My%20Phone)

The Microsoft APIs documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/pushpins/custom-image-pushpin-example) all require a registration and key because they're intended for Enterprise applications that support embedded maps in branded apps with the enterprise paying for use.

My application is FOSS and is intended for a private individual to plonk half a dozen points on a map in the course of trying to figure out where a phone was lost without consenting to being tracked by Google or a phone manufacturer.

The example above launches Bing maps and passes a point. Is there some kind of URL based way to get Bing maps to launch in its own right - not hosted in another app - and show a series of points for display as a path? If so, what search terms should be used when looking for details? The answer from which I lifted the sample has a link but it no longer produces the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just open the bing maps website with some information drawn on the map, the documentation for that is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/create-a-custom-map-url
To draw a polyline on the map, take a look at the section titled "collections" which describes how to add points, lines, or polygons to the map. As a quick example, this URL will create a simply polyline: https://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?sp=Polyline.47.68_-122.12_48.68_-123.12_49.68_-122.12_LINE_some%20notes_http://bing.com__%2300ff00__4px_Single_Solid

Comment: That is _exactly_ what I wanted.  Thank you! You've answered both parts of the question, although it might be prudent to copy the General Parameters and Examples sections into your answer, the policy on link answers is not without merit and Microsoft does decommission docs occasionally.