# Suppress collections pane

Tags: bing-maps

Apropos of this question [Supply path data to OpenStreetMaps or Bing Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998209) I'd like to make the page open with the collections pane collapsed. So far I haven't found any parameters relating to that.

Does anyone know of a parameter governing collections pane initial state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to force the pane to the closed state